# Reality vs Doppler calculations

Tags: doppler-effect

I just tried to explain Doppler and found a mismatch between by calculations and real world experience. I took a case of an ambulance approaching a listener going 67 mph (30 meters/sec) emitting a siren of stationary frequency 3000 Hz, and then passing at the same velocity. The answers I got were 3300 Hz and 2730 Hz, respectively. That didn't seem to match experience, so I found some sounds online of these pitches and sure enough, they do not match what I remember. The change in frequency sounds much greater as I remember it. What am I doing wrong?

Source moving towards observer:
$$f_\text{obs}=f\frac{V_\text{wave}}{V_\text{wave}-V_\text{source}}$$

Source moving away from observer:
$$f'_\text{obs}=f\frac{V_\text{wave}}{V_\text{wave}+V_\text{source}}$$

Comment: *"The change in frequency sounds much greater"* How are you determining this? Most humans can't hear what *frequency* a sound is, and additionally an ambulance siren is probably not a pure tone.

Comment: even if it is a frequency spectrum, my question and observation still holds. the drop in frequency in the real world sounds much more dramatic than the ~20% predicted by the formula. I took care to use real-life relatable sounds

Answer (score 1):

The Doppler formula you are using is for emitters that are traveling directly towards or away from the receiver. Since I assume that you did not get hit by the ambulance then it was not traveling directly towards or away from you. So indeed the change will be less dramatic than what is predicted by the formula you are using.

Comment: I had the opposite experience. The calculated difference UNDERESTIMATES my estimate of the change in frequency approaching versus after passing -- and by quite a bit. I listened to pitches online in this range and the sound in the world is MORE dramatic that the difference between  ~3300 HZ and ~2700 HZ.

Comment: "As I remember" is not a measurement, the frequency you heard is not just one, and if it is very loud you probably misjuged it. S next tim use you mobile to register the two sound and then use an analyzing tool you find easily on the net.

Comment: @CateB then you are misestimating either the velocity or the frequencies or both. The Doppler formula works and is the basis of a lot of other technologies and measurements

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: I failed to take into account the fact that volume is increasing upon approach and decreasing as the siren passes and recedes. That might be part of the difference in perception.